# Error: Host xxx is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql, database-connection

I'm trying to connect remotely to MySQL server as following:

below code works fine

```
mysql -u root -h localhost -p
```

below code returns me an error

```
 mysql -u root -h 'server ip_address here' -p
```

ERROR 1130 (00000): Host xxx is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Please help

Comment: That is because MySQL is not allowing you to connect from that address. Default is that only localhost van connect

Comment: You should configure mysql to allow remote connections. And also you should grant permission to the database you are connecting to from remote IP

Answer (score 18):

One has to create a `new MySQL User` and assign privileges as below in `Query prompt` via phpMyAdmin or command prompt:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Once done with all four queries, it should connect with `username / password`

`RESTART WAMP / LAMP Server` and it should work !

Comment: Can use 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES' to refresh the state without restarting server;

Answer (score 8):

Simply run de two commands below

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '**YourUserName**'@'**your IP**' IDENTIFIED BY '**yourPassoword**';

flush PRIVILEGES;
```

and It will be fine, go on :)

Comment: Thank you, I was just about to post the answer and noticed yours. I am updating it.

Comment: This helped so much. easy af.