# Error in Setup of a Remote MySQL Database connection via WordPress - Possible Solution

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, ip

Here is a link of an issue I found on Stackoverflow from a previous year - [Error: Host xxx is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288606/error-host-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server?lq=1)

The issue is I don't believe it is a wise idea to setup a universal user of % << Am I wrong in thinking this?

The solution I came up with is one I do not understand.

I have a server set with an IP of  xxx.123 and a database server with an IP of xxx.456

The wp-config file is held with the server set... the MySQL DB is thus held with the DB server.

I got the solution working by putting in the wp-config file the hostname of the IP of my DB thus xxx.456 >>> This makes sense to me because the config file has to point to somewhere.

The part I don't get is that in my DB MySQL User setup I have a name for the server of lets say wpUser that is both the localhost and an IP.  The only IP that works is that of my home wp-config file thus xxx.123 <<< Not the IP of the DB.

How is this possible?

So as a result, the wp-config file technically doesn't matchup with my actual MySQL DB...

If someone could explain this it would be greatly helpful.

I believe this is a better solution then applying a username and host of % which seems like a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary that you should use % in the place of hostname or IP and not specifically in WordPress environment.

In most of the cases people use wildcard (%) to grant the access to remote servers, but it is only advisory when your application is distributed across multiple servers, therefore those servers will be having multiple network IP addresses.

WordPress does not have that much wide distributed architecture. Only single connection will be created through single IP address or machine to access the data from the remote database.

Most of the cases people use local database or intranet network database where infrastructure management have taken care of the network security and network attacks such as brute force etc.

If you are using remote Mysql server with WordPress, you must configure you access as follows:

```
DBUser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

You can refer the following link of [MySql Security Advisors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-monitor/3.0/en/security-advisors-ref.html)